# Разобрать массив по div клонам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую всех!
Возник вопрос, вот решил узнать мнение. Имею данный код, все работает как мне надо, но никак не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы каждому клону div относился 1 массив из глобального массива. Т.е чтобы в container_1 - Store[0][j], в container_2 - Store[0][j]. Значение j будет постоянной в каждом блоке от 0 до 5. Перерыл кучу документации, но никак не найду наводки. Подскажите возможно ли вообще это сделать и возможный метод,функцию. Переборки работаю нормально, но информация вся отправленная в форму так же клонируется( Заранее благодарю!

```html
   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
var Store = [["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["11","12","13","14","15","16"],["17","18","19","20","21","22"]];
var Sum = Store.length;
</script>



<script> $(document).ready(function() {

    var cl = 1;

    for(var pr = 1; pr < Sum; pr++) {
    
        var clone = $("#container").clone(false)
        
        var cloneItems = clone.find("*[id]").andSelf();

        cloneItems.each(function() { 
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_" + cl);
        });
       
        clone.appendTo( ".clone-box" );
        cl++;
 
     }});

</script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="G">1</div>
  <div id="A">2</div>
  <div id="S">3</div>
  <div id="Y">4</div>
   <div id="F">5</div>
  <div id="P">6</div><br>
</div>

<div class="clone-box"></div>
```

Comment: Что такое `container_1` и `container_2`?

Comment: Когда создается клон, ему присваивается оригинальное имя. Т.е <div id="container_1">, <div id="container_2"> и т.д в зависимости от количества массивов.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы хотите, чтобы div блоки с `id="container"`, `id="container_1"` и `container_2` принимали значения 1-6, 11-16 и 17-22 соответственно?

Comment: Да, да!! Именно так! А у меня выходит что значение если приходит из массива (не важно какое именно), то копируется по всем клонам

Comment: А почему у вас начальное значение в цикле `1`? вот тут `for(var pr = 1; pr < Sum; pr++) {`?

Comment: Сначала подумал, что ошибся я, а нет. **1** потому что мне нужно клонирование **DIVов** исходя из количества массивов в массиве. Если стоит **0**, то создается **4 DIVа**, один из которых пустой, информации для него нет.

Comment: @Kirill, это все из-за того что первый уже создан, поэтому _показывается_ 4, а не создается

Comment: @Grundy, это я понимаю.Я имел в виду, что по факту я имею 4 DIVа сразу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственное что вам осталось сделать - заполнять текст дивов, из элементов соответствующих массивов, например методом [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) или [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Для выбора нужного элемента можно воспользоваться параметром `index` из функции [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
var Store = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"],
  ["17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var container = $("#container"),
    containers = Store.slice(1).map(function(el, index) {
      var clone = container.clone(); //клонируем элемент

      clone.children() // берем всех детей
        .text(function(i) { // устанавливаем нужный текст
          return el[i];
        }).andSelf() // добавляем в набор контейнер
        .attr("id", function(i, attr) { // устанавливаем нужный id
          return attr + '_' + (index + 1);
        });
      return clone; // возвращаем элемент
    });
  $(".clone-box").append(containers); //добавляем все созданное в общий контейнер
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.c {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.c div {
  border: 1px green solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<div id="container" class="c">
  <div id="G">1</div>
  <div id="A">2</div>
  <div id="S">3</div>
  <div id="Y">4</div>
  <div id="F">5</div>
  <div id="P">6</div>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="clone-box"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Буду внедрять) Думал о index, но не попробовал.

Comment: а как вы запоминаете функции и порядок их аргументов? К примеру js map(callback(element, index)) и jquery map(callback(index, element)), то есть наоборот. Работаю пока в сублиме, автокопплит для js и jqury, но он вроде не подсвечивает чей метод map.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, не так уж и сложно два случая запомнить: для массива и для jQuery объекта :) Ну и в справке написан порядок :) я ж все функции не помню

Comment: кроме map есть и другие повторяемые методы))

Comment: Все хорошо работает, но! Я планировал чтобы стандартные значения в DIV так же копировались, постоянно. Например 1 - 11, 2 - 12 и т.д. В другом клоне меняется только значение из нового массива) А сейчас выходит что постоянное выходит лишь 1 раз, а дальше див полностью заполняется массивом.

Comment: @Kirill, вообще ничего не понял :) был вопрос - как соотнести элемент массива с нужным дивом - пример отвечает на это, а уж текст - какой хочешь, такой и вставляй

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточность. Имею в виду, что код работает. Каждому DIVу присваивается значение из массивов, но оно заменяет значение из DIVа указанное в родителе. Т.е. в каждом клоне я планировал оставлять значение из родителя (это грубо говоря имя элемента массива) <div id="G">1</div> <div id="G_1">1</div> и так далее. С этим по другому разберусь)